# Using Meteor & GraphicsMagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I have Meteor v1 installed and GraphicsMagick installed.

When the app starts, the console tells me "GraphicsMagick found"

However when I try to follow these simple instructions: (https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/blob/master/README.md)

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , gm = require('./gm');

// resize and remove EXIF profile data
gm('/path/to/my/img.jpg')
.options({imageMagick: true})
.resize(240, 240)
...
```

I get "undefined is not a function" (referring to require('gm'))

Am I doing something wrong? How can I use GM in Meteor?

Comment: You need to use the Meteor package version of npm gm, you can try this one which looks OK : https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/graphicsmagick

Comment: That IS the package I'm using. Yet I keep getting undefined.

Comment: Then you can remove the require stuff and just reference gm because it's going to be globally accessible from the start.